# URL_NOT_RESET error REST API

Tags: rest-api, rest, apexrest, restresource

I have created the REST Resource to fetch the data from Salesforce. My Domain is also activated in our Org.

When I fetch the data using https://myDomain.my.salesforce.com/.../... it is returning me data but when I try with https://test.salesforce.com/.../... it is giving me below error

> [
>       {
>           "errorCode": "URL_NOT_RESET",
>           "message": "Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set"
>       }
>   ]

Let me know your thoughts on this

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`test.salesforce.com` or `login.salesforce.com` can be used to first login. Thereafter requests should be made using the `instance_url` and the `access_token` that you receive as a response on first login.

So, in your case you can used your Custom Domain but not the login URL.

Comment: Yes using instance_url which I got in response, I am successfully able to access the data, but is it possible that we can have both? I mean to say using test.salesforce.com also can access it?

Comment: In short, *NO*!