# Scratch org: call REST APIs via simple_salesforce

Tags: rest-api, python, simple-salesforce

I have a very simple python 3.x script that is getting errors when attempting to connect. So far, it simply consists of:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import pandas as pd

sf = Salesforce(instance_url='https://test.salesforce.com', session_id='<provided access token>')

metadata_sf = sf.Contact.describe()
```

When I do so, I get the error:

**SalesforceMalformedRequest: Malformed request https://test.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Contact/describe. Response content: [{'errorCode': 'URL_NOT_RESET', 'message': 'Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set'}]**

If I instead use the given URL, like this:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import pandas as pd

sf = Salesforce(instance_url='https://laguna-sobject-4136-dev-ed.scratch.my.salesforce.com', session_id='<provided access token>')

metadata_sf = sf.Contact.describe()
```

I get the following error:

**SalesforceExpiredSession: Expired session for https://laguna-sobject-4136-dev-ed.scratch.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Contact/describe. Response content: [{'message': 'Session expired or invalid', 'errorCode': 'INVALID_SESSION_ID'}]**

I need to find out how to deal with either the 'Malformed request' error, or find out how to refresh or renew the session ID. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Also, I did go into the Domain settings in Salesforce and clicked on 'Check Availability' and it came back with a green checkmark. Finally, the access token was obtained via an automated 'sforg' app generated from Slack. The credentials I received from it were Username, Profile Name, Id, Org Id, Access Token, Instance Url, Login Url, Alias, and Password.

Comment: The first error is a simple_salesforce bug (why; see [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217951/url-not-reset-error-rest-api)), you should open an issue on their github. The second error has many possible root causes. One possibility: license/permissions. See last couple of paragraphs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57880930/salesforce-api-to-get-a-record-throws-error-invalid-session)

Comment: Thanks @identigral for your response. The second links talks about the need to "obtain a fresh token by repeating the oAuth grant flow". Do you know how I can do this? This is a randomly-generated salesforce instance.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the steps that show how you obtained the access token.

Comment: done, thank you